# Mongoose execution with exec() or not?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am wondering what is the bestter way for execute my Mongoose query in this case:

```js
// 1
AgentLogs.find(searchParams)
  .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
  .exec(function (err, docs) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.json(docs);
    })
  .lean();

// 2
AgentLogs.find(searchParams, (err, docs) => {
  if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.json(docs);
  })
.sort({ timestamp: -1 })
.lean();
```

I "prefer" number 2, but beside my feelings what is the better or "right" way? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the majority of use cases both options will work in similar way.

For some reason, mongoose uses its own promise-like implementation but not the real promises. It means that queries are actually *thenable* and also can be used with async/await but those are not instances of a real `Promise`.

When you call `.exec()` it forces mongoose to return a real, fully fledged Promise object.

The main difference between these two approaches is that an `exec` one can provide you more details and context information if error occurs - and that is the main reason why using `exec` is recommended.

There is a separate [article](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) related to this topic in the mongoose docs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. I did not see it before somehow Oo